(Windows) No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8'
I am trying to setup gaussian splatting with conda, however when it comes to installing the submodules - diff-gaussian-rasterization & simple-knn, it reports the error "No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8'". Though I already have CUDA=11.8 installed with Visual Studio 2019. The following is the error generated.
Also, in the conda env, even though I have installed pytorch using the following line:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.8 -c pytorch

torch with cuda support is still false
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False

If anyone has any thought on this, please let me know. Much appreciated!!
Error Generated
 Channels:
 - pytorch
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting Packages:

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - "By downloading and using the CUDA Toolkit conda packages, you accept the terms and conditions of the CUDA End User License A

done
Installing pip dependencies: | Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['C:\\Users\\dizhang\\anaconda3\\envs\\gaussian_splatting\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', 'C:\\Users\\dizhang\\dev\\research\\gaussi]
Pip subprocess output:
Processing c:\users\dizhang\dev\research\gaussian_splatting\gaussian-splatting\submodules\diff-gaussian-rasterization
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Processing c:\users\dizhang\dev\research\gaussian_splatting\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: diff_gaussian_rasterization, simple_knn
  Building wheel for diff_gaussian_rasterization (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for diff_gaussian_rasterization (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for diff_gaussian_rasterization
  Building wheel for simple_knn (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for simple_knn (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for simple_knn
Failed to build diff_gaussian_rasterization simple_knn
Installing collected packages: simple_knn, diff_gaussian_rasterization
  Running setup.py install for simple_knn: started
  Running setup.py install for simple_knn: finished with status 'error'

Pip subprocess error:
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [52 lines of output]
      No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8'
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      copying diff_gaussian_rasterization\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\diff_gaussian_rasterization
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\dev\research\gaussian_splatting\gaussian-splatting\submodules\diff-gaussian-rasterization\setup.py", line 32, in <modul>
          'build_ext': BuildExtension
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 88, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 434, in build_extensions
          self._check_cuda_version(compiler_name, compiler_version)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 808, in _check_cuda_version
          torch_cuda_version = packaging.version.parse(torch.version.cuda)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 52, in parse
          return Version(version)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 196, in __init__
          match = self._regex.search(version)
      TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for diff_gaussian_rasterization
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]
      No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8'
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\dev\research\gaussian_splatting\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
          'build_ext': BuildExtension
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 88, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 434, in build_extensions
          self._check_cuda_version(compiler_name, compiler_version)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 808, in _check_cuda_version
          torch_cuda_version = packaging.version.parse(torch.version.cuda)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 52, in parse
          return Version(version)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 196, in __init__
          match = self._regex.search(version)
      TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for simple_knn
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for simple_knn did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [65 lines of output]
      No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8'
      running install
      C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py ins.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
              standards-based tools.

              See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        self.initialize_options()
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\dev\research\gaussian_splatting\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
          'build_ext': BuildExtension
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 78, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 697, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 88, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 434, in build_extensions
          self._check_cuda_version(compiler_name, compiler_version)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 808, in _check_cuda_version
          torch_cuda_version = packaging.version.parse(torch.version.cuda)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 52, in parse
          return Version(version)
        File "C:\Users\dizhang\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 196, in __init__
          match = self._regex.search(version)
      TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> simple_knn

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

YAML file generated the above error when created conda env
name: gaussian_splatting
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - cudatoolkit=11.8
  - plyfile=0.8.1
  - python=3.7.13
  - pip=22.3.1
  - pytorch=1.12.1
  - torchaudio=0.12.1
  - torchvision=0.13.1
  - tqdm
  - pip:
    - submodules/diff-gaussian-rasterization
    - submodules/simple-knn

Driver Version
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 555.85                 Driver Version: 555.85         CUDA Version: 12.5     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Driver-Model | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070      WDDM  |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   40C    P8              9W /  200W |     649MiB /  12282MiB |      2%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+

Visual Studio
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30154 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Thank you!
I have tried to reinstall the driver but I think the driver is irrelevant in this case, since my CUDA toolkit version is 11.8.
Also, I had VS 2022 Community installed initially, and suspected there could be an compatibility issue so I installed 2019 instead and reinstalled cuda afterwards as well. But all of these did not seem to work.
Also, the other problem I am curious about is that in my system variables I have
CUDA_PATH = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8
CUDA_PATH_V11.8 = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8

and in path I have
%CUDA_PATH%\bin
%CUDA_PATH%\libnvvp

However, when reporting the error it is CUDA_HOME instead of CUDA_PATH. WHY is that? Where is it get the CUDA_HOME path from?
No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8'


Im not sure if this will work, but I just resolved the issue of submodules (i think), try using VS 2022 again and get cuda 12.4 and then select the appriopriate torch package, in setup.py for KNN and gaussian raus... if torch is not recognised after the conda install, try installing it with pip too
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
if there are some VS errors go into ur NVIDIA gpu computing toolkit -> CUDA -> V11.8 -> include -> crt -> host_config_.h and on line 151 where it says
#if _MSC_VER < 1910 || _MSC_VER >= 1940 i changed 1940 to 1950,
let me know if it works
oh and make sure u also choose the right conda environment in vs with ctrl + shift + P and python interpreter (im not sure if this contributed to it working but ill type it anyway)
